# Initializer for conditional binding must have optional type, but I use optional type already

Tags: json, swift3

So I implemented JSONSerialization to convert data from JSON, but the code give error initializer for conditional binding must have optional type (since i use if let, to provide additional code if its true) but then I use the type Data? from completion handler, which is optional. Why is this?

```
let etaReq = session.dataTask(with: etaURLreq as URLRequest)
    {

        (data, response, error) in

        if error == nil
        {
            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse

            if (httpResponse?.statusCode)! >= 200 && (httpResponse?.statusCode)! <= 299
            {

                print("Good status code \(httpResponse?.statusCode)")
                print(data?.description)

                do
                {

                    if let jsonDataArray = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data (here is the error), options: [])
                    {

                    }

                }
```

Comment: Usually the compiler is right :) – `try! SomeThingThatThrows()` does *not* return an optional. Perhaps you meant `try? SomeThingThatThrows()` ? Or `do/try/catch` ?

Comment: Oh foolish me! thanks so much I changed try! to try? and it solved it thanks again @MartinR